# make html input contain something to validate

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

Basically i want a html input to must contain something.
So i am wanting to make the user submit a mp3 url so i want the input to contain mp3 and wont validate if it doesn't . I have already done.

```html
<input type="url" />
```

But that just makes sure its a url.
Not an mp3 url.
To be clear i cant just do value=".mp3" because the user could delete it.
I'm thinking i am going to have to use java script for this.

Comment: You can provide value in "value" attribute...

Comment: @Rayon Wont that just add .mp3 to the input box. Couldn't the user just delete it.

Comment: I feel I took you wrong, Could you elaborate what you mean by _"html input to must contain something"_ ?

Comment: The input will only allow any type of url. If you are wanting for the visitor to upload a file also you will need <input type='file' accept="audio/*" ...>

Comment: You can make it readOnly... Or you can have "type='hidden'" to keep the value...

Comment: @Rayon sorry its my bad wording. i want it to not validate it there if it doesn't contain. mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this short code to validate if the input does include the substring `.mp3`, with a file name preceding it.

It actually checks if the input string matches the regex `.+\.mp3`. It doesn't check other requirements that I would consider if I were you (valid characters in the file name, for example).

I can tell you're a beginner so I've simplified it, even though it can be written in a more abbreviated form.

```js
function check() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  var output = document.getElementById("result");

  if (input.value.match(/.+\.mp3/g))
    output.innerHTML = "Contains '.mp3'";
  else
    output.innerHTML = "Doesn't contain '.mp3'";
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="url" />
<button onclick="check()">check</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="url" value="mp3" />
```

You shouldn't have made too much research before asking here...

EDIT -----

If you want to validate the data, you'll need to use Javascript or PHP to check the value of the input.

If you want obviously to get something (no matter what) in the value, use this :

```
<input type="url" value="mp3" required="required" />
```

If you obviously want "mp3" as value, set this input type to "hidden" so that it won't appear on user's screen :

```
<input type="hidden" value="mp3" />
```

Comment: Sorry i fogot one detail.I want to make it  so it won't validate if it doesn't contain .mp3